# Creating an Alpine container in LXC on top of Ubuntu

Tags: lxc

I've got a new server spun up with Ubuntu Server and LXC installed for apt. I've been reading the docs and trying to understand how to import images/templates. I'm having a hard time understanding how to import a list of public images and specifically how to setup a new instance with Alpine. I believe this can be done with a tarball of the ISO (from the man page) but there's also a remote option.

The LXC container list here: https://us.images.linuxcontainers.org/ says these are available via lxc-download template which I assumed was a command to trigger a template but now I'm just more confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using LXC, typically you would set up a new container with a command like this:

```
lxc-create -n ${c} -t download -- -d ${d} -r ${r} -a amd64
```

where `c` is the container name of your choosing, `d` is the distro such as 'alpine', and `r` is the version number of the release.  Here is an example:

```
# lxc-create -n test -t download -- -d alpine -r 3.12 -a amd64
The cached copy has expired, re-downloading...
Setting up the GPG keyring
Downloading the image index
Downloading the rootfs
Downloading the metadata
The image cache is now ready
Unpacking the rootfs

---
You just created an Alpinelinux 3.12 x86_64 (20201213_13:00) container.
```

Comment: Doesn't matter what combination I use it keeps throwing errors. I recently tried sudo lxc-create --name container-one -t alpine -- --release edge and it failed to create because of unknown template "alpine".

Comment: This command is not using the syntax in the answer.

Comment: I managed to get the command you recommended working. Thanks.